# Long compile times when compiling Unreal Engine Source

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, unreal-engine4

According to the documentation a full compile of the UE4 source shouldn't take longer than 40 minutes.

I am trying to compile UE 4.27 using VS 2017 in Windows and its taking all day!
The instructions simply say to select the UE4 project in Solution Explorer, right click and select 'Build.

I can see every single module being compiled ie

> 455/4705] Module.SequenceRecorder.gen.cpp

How can I speed up compilation times?

Comment: The first thing is to make sure your source and build folders are on a fast ssd. You could also double check vs to make sure it's building using most or all available cpu cores. You can also enable unity builds on the unreal build tool. Also a full rebuild isn't something you should be doing often - so I wouldn't get too worried about a ridiculous first build time. And, I'd recommend updating to vs19, the linker was significantly improved and is noticeably faster.

Answer (score 1):

Unreal Engine is a massive piece of software.

Your compile times will depend on a lot of factors, most importantly the hardware your compiling with.

The 40 minutes compile time is only a guideline estimate, they cannot guarantee that across all specs.

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/3647/how-to-improve-compile-times-for-a-c-project.html